# Remove spaces from field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a function that removes all the spaces (single or multiple) in a field anywhere in the column. For Example, if a tag = [B00 -PCV  6143-C-], it would get changed to [B00-PCV6143-C-].

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use `replace()`:

```
select replace(tag, ' ', '') as TagWithNoSpaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE()`

```
SELECT REPLACE('[B00 -PCV 6143-C-]',' ','')
```

[REPLACE() - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)